# Created a jar file and frames are not opening in jar while they open in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, frames

I have created a project which has more than 2 ".java" files for each frame like `home.java` and `control.java`. There is a button in `home.java` upon clicking which opens the frame for `control.java`. This works when ran from Netbeans but when created a jar file the first frame opens. But the second frame isn't opening. Please help.

**Home.java:**

```
public class home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public home() {
        initComponents();
    }
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
       setVisible(false);
       new controls().setVisible(true);// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new home().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    } 


     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
      setVisible(false);
      new controls().setVisible(true);
    }
```

**CONTROLS.java:**

```
public class controls extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form controls
 */
public controls() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {          

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new controls().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show us the constructor for the `controls` class. A little more information is needed.

Comment: He got the Output in Netbeans.. Jar not working...

Comment: added the code.... yea akshay i got the code working..switching between the frames on button click is happenening from netbeans but when i created the jar file..i can only run the home.java and when i click on button home.java hides and controls.java is not opening..

Comment: I have tried ur code in my env. I didn't find any behavior from Clicking on jar file as well as Open the Jar file using java -jar "C:\Documents and Settings\Ayush\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\dist\JavaApplication1.jar" both ways i got the correct Result.

Comment: Right click on Project and do CLean and Build option, Go to the Dist folder, try run the Jar folder in Dist folder

Comment: still the same thing...the second frame on button click isnt opening...are the codes proper?

Comment: how would u put the code when u want to switch between frames on button click..

Answer (score 0):

Set the other frame visible before setting the first invisible.

Comment: the second frame isnt opening after trying what you said.. after clicking the button i am not getting any behavior in jar file..while i get it working when i run it from netbeans..